# moving items in 2d array python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to recreate the game 2048 as a project and i'm having trouble with manipulating the 2d array. I'm trying to move the elements in the 2d array around and without them going off the screen.

```
def move(self, direction):

    if (self.d == UP):
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                if(self.line[i][j]!= self.line[0][0]):
                    self.line[i][j] = self.line[i + 1][j]
                    self.line[i + 1][j] = self.line[i + 2][j] 
                    self.line[i + 2][j] = self.line[i + 3][j]
```

this is what i currently have just for them to move up and they always seem to either disappear or fails.

Comment: You need to set a limit - you're letting the indices go above 3.

Comment: I thought i set the limit at the second if statement. How would i do that correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I made this might be what you are looking for, it is in JavaScript because I am not currently on my own computer but here it is:

```
function up(tbl) {
    var x = 0;
    while (x < tbl[0].length) {
        do {
            var move = 0;
            var y = 0;
            while (y < tbl.length - 1) {
                if (tbl[y][x] == 0 && tbl[y + 1][x] != 0) {
                    tbl[y][x] = tbl[y + 1][x];
                    tbl[y + 1][x] = 0;
                    move = 1;
                }
                else if (tbl[y][x] != 0 && tbl[y][x] == tbl[y + 1][x]) {
                    tbl[y][x] += tbl[y + 1][x];
                    tbl[y + 1][x] = 0;
                    move = 1;
                }
                y++;
            }
        } while (move == 1)
        x++;
    }
    return tbl;
}

/* Just a testing table */
var t = [[1,   1,   0,   1],
         [0,   2,   2,   8],
         [0,   128, 1,   1],
         [2,   0,   1,   4]];

up(t);
```

What it does is go column by column, from the top to bottom, and checks:

- if there is a gap, and the cell under it isn't, it moves the cell up
- else if two cells are the same number, they are added up if none of
- if after one loop (from top to bottom), neither of the above conditions took place, it moves to the next column

Also, in case you would like to apply this for the three other directions, I recommend rotating the table instead of doing 3 more of the above function. If you have trouble transcribing it to Python, I'll be able to help you later this evening.

EDIT:

Here you go, the same thing, but in Python:

```
def up(tbl):
    x = 0
    while (x < len(tbl[0])):
        while True:
            move = 0
            y = 0
            while (y < (len(tbl) - 1)):
                if (tbl[y][x] == 0 and tbl[y + 1][x] != 0):
                    tbl[y][x] = tbl[y + 1][x]
                    tbl[y + 1][x] = 0
                    move = 1
                elif (tbl[y][x] != 0 and tbl[y][x] == tbl[y + 1][x]):
                    tbl[y][x] += tbl[y + 1][x]
                    tbl[y + 1][x] = 0
                    move = 1
                y = y + 1
            if (move == 0):
                break
        x = x + 1
    return tbl

t = [[1,   1,   0,   1],
     [0,   2,   2,   8],
     [0,   128, 1,   1],
     [2,   0,   1,   4]];

up(t)

print('\n'.join([''.join(['{:5}'.format(item) for item in row]) for row in t]))
```

Oh, and the original 2048 does not allow a tile to merge twice during the same turn, so you might want to tweak the elif to fit that, since it merges them until it cannot anymore.